# Passing LatLng between fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm building an app where I need to pass a LatLng from one fragment to another.  Currently, I'm doing that with this method:

```
public static LocationsFragment newInstance(LatLng latLng){
    LocationsFragment fragment = new LocationsFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    double x = latLng.latitude;
    double y = latLng.longitude;
    bundle.putDouble(PATIENT_LAT, x);
    bundle.putDouble(PATIENT_LON, y);
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    return fragment;
}
```

As you can see, I'm taking the LatLng and breaking it up to doubles.  In the fragment I have to put it back together.  I tried using a serializable ie: bundle.putSerializable(latlng); but that didn't work.  Is there a way to pass a LatLng w/o having to unpack it? This works, but I would rather do it more efficiently if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no performance issues here, you are simply putting to double values into the `Bundle` and then reading them. This is not a heavy operation and this is how Android is intended to work. Other ways such as sending a broadcast message or a `Message` to a handler, they all require packing a value into the `Bundle`, I don't think there can be anything better then that.

Also, `setArguments` will help your app to recreate the fragment if needed and those arguments will still be there. If you used a constructor with parameters that wouldn't work.

You will be able to put `latLng` as a `Serializable` if this class implements a serializable interface. But I think two double values will be more efficient if you are really concerned about the performance. Although I can't think of such use case where passing arguments in a bundle between fragments might be a problem.